# Convert the given lists into dictionary using Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Lets say we have a set of input lists:

```
lst= [country,usa,uk,india,japan],
[city,tokyo,berlin,moscow,abudhabi],
[planet,earth,mars,venus]
```

We want to create a dictionary in python for each of these lists, so that the output looks like:

```
mydict= {country:[usa,uk,india,japan]},
{city:[tokyo,berlin,moscow,abudhabi]},
{planet:[earth,mars,venus]}
```

Comment: please provide a minimal code implementation that we can help you debug/investigate.

Comment: Your dict is not a dictionary

Comment: In your example: set of input lists = this type is actually a `tuple` so both and `lst` and `set` are confusing. `mydict` is actually a `tuple` with 3 one-key dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension and slicing for that

```py
lst= [[country,usa,uk,india,japan],
[city,tokyo,berlin,moscow,abudhabi],
[planet,earth,mars,venus]]

result = [{l[0]:l[1:]} for l in lst]
```

here I have assumed that lst is a list of lists you want to create a list of dictionaries from it. This was not 100% clear from you question.

Comment: original result `mydict` was actually a `tuple` :) so result could be `tuple({l[0]:l[1:]} for l in lst)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this valid python input:

```
lst = [['country','usa','uk','india','japan'],
       ['city','tokyo','berlin','moscow','abudhabi'],
       ['planet','earth','mars','venus']]
```

Use `zip`, and the `dict` constructor:

```
keys, *vals = zip(*lst)
d = dict(zip(keys, map(list,vals)))
```

Output:

```
{'country': ['usa', 'uk', 'india', 'japan'],
 'city': ['tokyo', 'berlin', 'moscow', 'abudhabi'],
 'planet': ['earth', 'mars', 'venus']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you did not use strings and the list you gave was not a nested list so I modified the code based on my understanding of your code.

The list is defined by

```
lst= [['country','usa','uk','india','japan'],
['city','tokyo','berlin','moscow','abudhabi'],
['planet','earth','mars','venus']]
```

to convert it to a dictionary I used

```
dict={lst[0][0]:lst[0][1:5],
      lst[1][0]:lst[1][1:5],
      lst[2][0]:lst[2][1:4]}
```

and this is what printing the dictionary looks like

```
{'city': ['tokyo', 'berlin', 'moscow', 'abudhabi'],
 'country': ['usa', 'uk', 'india', 'japan'],
 'planet': ['earth', 'mars', 'venus']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the input you want:

```
lst = [['country','usa','uk','india','japan'],
       ['city','tokyo','berlin','moscow','abudhabi'],
       ['planet','earth','mars','venus']]
```

and the output is a single dictionary like this:

```
{'country': ['usa', 'uk', 'india', 'japan'], 'city': ['tokyo', 'berlin', 'moscow', 'abudhabi'], 'planet': ['earth', 'mars', 'venus']}
```

You can use dict comprehension with list unpacking to get the result:

```
mydict = {k: vals for (k, *vals) in lst}
```